# HTML/CSS Navbar formating issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to duplicate http://csswizardry.com/demos/centred-nav/ but make the menu at the top of the screen. I have reviewed some of the tutorials on w3schools and a few others but still cant figure out why it is not going to the top to begin with. Below is the my style.css

```
body    { 
width:960px; 
top:0px;

padding:10px 0; 
margin:0 auto;
font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
}
#nav{
border:1px solid #ccc;
border-width:1px 0;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-align:center;
}
#nav li{
display:inline;
}
#nav a{
display:inline-block;
padding:102px;
}
a{
color:#c00;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
}
a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Below is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Photography</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<div id="container">
    <div id="topnav">
        <ul id="nav">
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: http://imgur.com/s4tziNh

For the screenshot. I want to remove the whitespace above the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
#nav a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 102px;
}
```

to

```
#nav a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 102px 0 0;
}
```

and probably add in this too to remove the right side padding from the final child element

```
#nav a:last-child {
    padding:0;
}
```

You're applying 102px padding all around the `a` tags, needs to just be on the right side :)

Comment: Maybe your container has margin/padding on it. Adding all your css would help out a lot

Comment: it appears to be a caching issue as when I put the css code into the main html, it works fine. :(

Comment: So you only have this issue when it's added to the css file?

Comment: yes. I think maybe firefox isnt seeing the css was updated and reverts to a cached copy.

Answer (score -2):

```
body    { 
width:960px; 
top:0px;

/*############  change padding from 10px to 0px  ##########*/

padding:0px 0; 
margin:0 auto;
font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
}
#nav{
border:1px solid #ccc;
border-width:1px 0;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-align:center;
}
#nav li{
display:inline;
}
#nav a{
display:inline-block;
padding:10px;
}
a{
color:#c00;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
}
a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

There was more padding for `#nav a{}`

Comment: Explanation? What did you change and why?

Comment: there was more padding for #nav a{

Comment: Pretty certain that gap at the top is larger than 10px. You also don't need to make body { padding: 0px 0 }. Just body { padding: 0 } would do fine. But as i say, i doubt this is the issue